# Messages not forwarded to error queue when exception is thrown in handler (it works on my machine)

Tags: c#, nservicebus

We are using NServicebus 4.0.5 with sql server(sql server 2012) as transport. When the handler throws an exception, NSB does not retry or move the message to the error queue. Successful messages make it to the 
audit queue but the failed/errored ones don't! . Interestingly, all this works on our local machines(windows 7 ,sql server localdb) but not on windows server 2012 (sql server 2012). Here is the config info on the subscriber:

```
<add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial 
Catalog=NServiceBus;Integrated Security=SSPI;Enlist=false;" />
    <add name="NServiceBus/Persistence" connectionString="Data 
Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=NServiceBus;Integrated 
Security=SSPI;Enlist=false;" />
<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" /> 
  <UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit"> 
    <MessageEndpointMappings> 
      <add Assembly="Services.Section.Messages" Endpoint=
"Services.ACL.Worker" /> 
    </MessageEndpointMappings> 
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

And in code it is configured as follows:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, 
IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            IContainer container = ContainerInstanceProvider.
GetContainerInstance();

            Configure
                .Transactions.Enable();
            Configure.With()
                     .AutofacBuilder(container)
                     .UseTransport<SqlServer>()
                     .Log4Net()
                     //.Serialization.Json()
                     .UseNHibernateSubscriptionPersister()
                     .UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister()
                     .MessageForwardingInCaseOfFault()
                     .RijndaelEncryptionService()
                     .DefiningCommandsAs(type => type.Namespace != null &&type
.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"))
                     .DefiningEventsAs(type => type.Namespace != null &&type
.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"))
                     .UnicastBus();

        }

    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

here is the log info (there is a lot there, search for error to see the relevant parts)

https://gist.github.com/ranji/7378249

Comment: I've checked out samples and tests and they all work. What version of Windows + SqlServer are you on?

Comment: Side note: you need to move the conventions right after the .With() statement for them to be picked up. You can also remove Transactions.Enable() since that is the default

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund local machine = win 7 + sql server localdb (vs2012), deployed server = win 2012 +sql server 2012

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund I added the log info here https://gist.github.com/ranji/7378249